# Maven install is giving error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project, when I run `mvn install`, I get an error like:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) on project jdbc.demo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar from central failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 9941; received: 815 -> [Help 1]

I tried different answers posted to the similar questions like deleting `.m2` repo etc, but couldn't solve the problem.

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pps</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc.demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jdbc.demo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.pps.jdbc.demo.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Edit:
When I couln't figure out the source of problem, I created a simple maven project using eclipse, added a class that prints `Hello-World`, didn't change the pom, and run `mvn install`, still I got same error. The `pom.xml` file has nothing that could be wrong:

```
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello.java</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong I am doing? This could be very simple but took a a day to correct and I havn't recieved any hit yet.

I am using `Apache Maven 3.0.5`.

Comment: Behind a proxy or corporate firewall?

Comment: I don't think so. I even ran the command as `sudo`, still no luck. :(